# Elasticsearch - Search NOT IN

Tags: elasticsearch, foselasticabundle

I got lot of documents defined nearly like that:

```
{
   "id": 1,
   "createdBy": 1379662
   "content": "foo"
}
{
   "id": 2,
   "createdBy": 549674
   "content": "bar"
}
```

I'm trying to get all documents where `createdBy` is not in a list:

```
{
  "post_filter":{
     "bool":{
        "must_not":[
           {
              "term":{
                 "createdBy":[
                    1379662,
                    18475
                 ]
              }
           }
        ]
     }
  },
  "query":{
     "match_all":{

     }
  }
}
```

But with that I still get the document create by 1379662.
If I use only one value in my array, it's works

```
"term":{
    "createdBy":[1379662]
}
```

Were're using an old version of ES (1.7.5) on this project. But there is a solution?

Thanks for helping

**Bouffe**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `terms` instead of `term`

```
{
  "post_filter":{
     "bool":{
        "must_not":[
           {
              "terms":{               <--- change this
                 "createdBy":[
                    1379662,
                    18475
                 ]
              }
           }
        ]
     }
  },
  "query":{
     "match_all":{

     }
  }
}
```

Comment: I feel ashamed...
Thanks for awser me!